# What's the correct way to return a 'not found' response from a GRPC c++ server implementation?

Tags: c++, grpc

I'm looking through the guides and documentation, but am not deeply familiar with idiomatic C++ programming. In all the server implementation cases I've seen, the response `grpc::Status::OK` is returned at the end of an RPC implementation, for example:

(from https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/examples/cpp/helloworld/greeter_server.cc)

```
class GreeterServiceImpl final : public Greeter::Service {
  Status SayHello(ServerContext* context, const HelloRequest* request,
                  HelloReply* reply) override {
    std::string prefix("Hello ");
    reply->set_message(prefix + request->name());
    return Status::OK;
  }
};
```

Is the expected pattern of implementation that Status::OK is *always* returned? Are there other options that you should return on failure conditions (such as a 404 response to a requested resource not being found)?

Or is it expected that you'll encode the relevant error conditions into your own proto messages, and always reply with a message that possibly contains the error details?

I thought the documentation reflected that there were other status codes that could be returned (NOT_FOUND for example), but when I tried that I'm getting a compilation error:

`No member named 'NOT_FOUND' in 'grpc::Status'; did you mean 'grpc::NOT_FOUND'?`

And the method doesn't like it if I'm not returning `grpc::NOT_FOUND`, as it's an incompatible type.

Comment: there are more values for `Status` than just `Status::OK`, closest to 404 is probably `Status::NOT_FOUND`

Comment: I thought that's what the documentation reflected, but when I tried that, I get a compilation error: `No member named 'NOT_FOUND' in 'grpc::Status'; did you mean 'grpc::NOT_FOUND'?`

And the method doesn't like it if I'm not returning grpc::NOT_FOUND, as it's an incompatible type.

Comment: For those stumbling upon this thread in the future, the problem here was the confusion between grpc's `Status` class and its `StatusCode` enumeration, as can be seen in the accepted solution

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can return an explicitly generated status by creating a Status() with a code and message, for example:

```
return grpc::Status(grpc::StatusCode::NOT_FOUND, "error details here");
```

and return that instead of `Status::OK` to send an error message;